# How to configure jetty max headers size in spring application

Tags: java, spring, jetty, cloud-foundry

I have a spring application that uses jetty server. i need to change the max size of the header in order to send large size headers.

i added jetty to my dependencies like this:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

can i add a bean that will configure this?

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, you can configure the embedded Jetty container by following the instructions [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-jetty).

Answer (score 1):

Extending the max URL length reuires enlarging the HTTP Header buffer size, both in Tomcat and Jetty.

Using embedded servlet container in Spring Boot this is done setting `maxHttpHeaderSize` property to an appropriate value.

The current released version of Spring Boot (1.3.x) supports it **for Tomcat only**, using `server.tomcat.max-http-header-size` Spring Boot configuration property.

See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.3.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L751

The latest Spring Boot version seems to support it for Jetty as well, using `server.max-http-header-size`, but has not been released yet:

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L981